# Ubuntu logs automatically into Unity-2D mode

Tags: unity, resolution, unity-2d

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04. The computer is an Acer Aspire 5732Z and I have 2 problems:

1. When I log onto Ubuntu (in 3D mode) it begins in 2D mode.
2. I cannot change the screen resolution.

Since installing it at first, the screen appeared black, causing problems, but I solved it with the "nomodeset".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same computer and the same problem. The Acer Aspire 5732Z uses the "Mobile Intel® GL40 Express Chipset ... featuring Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 4500M" and has a native LCD resolution of 1366 x 768 and 1080p support in the hardware (see http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/2009/acer/aspire/Aspire5732Z/Aspire5732Zsp2.shtml). But as long as I have to use nomodeset to boot without a black screen, Linux won't let me use native or 1080p resolution. So the basic problem is needing nomodeset to boot. Other Debian-based distros have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `nomodeset` with display effects and settings, as `nomodeset` tels Linux to use a more reliable, but not as feature-packed(it is quite simple and plain), video driver mode. You may try `sudo apt-get install flgrx` and then try disabling `nomodeset`, if you have an ATI graphics card. `nomodeset` also disables 3d effects.

Comment: changes reinvested
I did sudo gedit /etc/default/grub 
and went back to leave the line as it was before:
put GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash".
And start ubuntu without problems, and missed getting the black screen.
But remains in 2D mode and I can not change the resolution of the screen: (

Comment: @user60108 What vireo drivers are you using? The default? Or new drivers you manually installed with Additional driver tool or command line?

Comment: I'm using the default, as additional driver tool not found any..

Comment: Dies the additional driver tool operate without `nomodeset` enabled? Try it again without nomodeset and see if it works.

Comment: No:(, aditional driver tool not found any..